# How to size DatePicker dialog and change the mode to spinner style in Xamarin.Forms cross platform?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Trying to re-size the height and width of datepicker dialog box in xamarin.forms. 
Also, i want to change the mode to spinner style.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, i want to change the mode to spinner style.

I have been able to do this modifying the Theme of the app. In the Android project specifically in Resources > values there is a style.xml file.

Add this:

```
<style name="DatePickerStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

inside the `resources` tags and modify the style called `AppCompatDialogStyle` to look like:

```
<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/DatePickerStyle</item>
</style>
```

This will help you with changing the datepickermode to a spinner.

Regarding modifying the **height** and **width** of the Dialog that appears I don't know if there is an easy way to do it (or a if there's one at all). This is fully managed by Android. I tried playing with the style properties and none of them worked as these seem to affect the inside spinner and not the outer dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To resize the dialog, I used the properties on a DatePickerDialog inside a custom renderer.

```
dialog.DatePicker.SetMinimumHeight(200);
dialog.DatePicker.SetMinimumWidth(200);
```